# shapefiles wont associate with feature datasets

Tags: python-3.x, arcgis

##I have a python code that converts different coordinates and crates a new shapefile folder as it should. I then create a gdb with point, line and polygon feature datasets however when viewed in arcGIS pro the shapefiles are no where to be found. Looking at the code below does anyone understand why?

```
## 1. Import arcpy and os modules
import arcpy
import os

## 2. Set up arcpy environment and convert coordinate system
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\\Users\\ddste\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Projects\\Assignment1 Project"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = "True"
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference(2193)
arcpy.env.geographicTransformations = "New_Zealand_1949_To_NZGD_2000_3_NTv2"

## 3. Decide on output storage structure (folder or geodatabase) to reorganise files
gdb_name = "NZ_gdb1.gdb"
gdb_path = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, gdb_name)
if not arcpy.Exists(gdb_path):
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(arcpy.env.workspace, gdb_name)
    
## 4. Create feature datasets for different shapefile types
feature_datasets = ["points", "lines", "polygons"]
for fd_name in feature_datasets:
    fd_path = os.path.join(gdb_path, fd_name)
    if not arcpy.Exists(fd_path):
        arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(gdb_path, fd_name)

## 5. Find all shapefiles in subfolders and access data in Qmap
os.chdir(r"C:\\Users\\ddste\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Projects\\Assignment1 Project\\QMAP_data")
wd = os.getcwd()
shapefile_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(wd):
    for file in files:
        if file == "geol_u_p.shp":
            shapefile_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            region_name = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(shapefile_path))[-1]
            shapefile_list.append(shapefile_path)

## 6. Merge all geol_u_p shapefiles into one new shapefile for NZ
output_path = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, "NewZ_geol_u_p.shp")
arcpy.Merge_management(shapefile_list, output_path)

## 7. Loop through shapefiles and add them to appropriate feature dataset
output_gdb = gdb_path
for shapefile_path in shapefile_list:
    test = shapefile_path.split(os.path.sep)
    region = test[6]
    featureN = test[-1]
    outname = region + "_" + featureN
    desc = arcpy.Describe(shapefile_path)
    shape_type = desc.shapeType
    if shape_type == "Point":
        outname = region + "_" + featureN + "_points"
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(shapefile_path,output_gdb,outname)
    elif shape_type == "Polyline":
        outname = region + "_" + featureN + "_lines"
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(shapefile_path,output_gdb,outname)
    elif shape_type == "Polygon":
        outname = region + "_" + featureN + "_polygons"
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(shapefile_path,output_gdb,outname)
```